# How to open a jar file in a Cocoa App

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am trying to execute a jar in my Cocoa app. My research tells me I should use `NSTask`. However, I am only able to get `system()` to work. E.g.:

```
// This works
system("cd /path/to ; /usr/bin/java -jar file.jar");
```

But this doesn't work:

```
// This does not work
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/java"];
[task setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"-jar", @"/path/to/test.jar", nil] ];
[task launch];
```

I get a class not found Java exception when I run my app because it cannot find its dependencies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no general error in your code, I tried it out myself.

I assume that you have defined a **CLASSPATH** environment variable in your *.profile*, *.bashrc* or whatever, that is required to execute the Java file.

`system()` uses the shell to execute your command, and therefore the CLASSPATH is inherited by the `java` command.

`NSTask` on the other hand does *not* use the shell, so `java` would not know about the CLASSPATH from your profile.

The solution would be to add `@"-cp", @"<your class path>"` to the arguments.

**UPDATE**

As it turned out in the discussion, the problem in this case was not the class path, but the *current working directory*. Adding

```
[task setCurrentDirectoryPath:@"/path/to"]
```

solved the issue.

Comment: Martin, by attaching that Jar to an `NSTask` enable me to kill the execution of the Jar once the program exit? Also, how can I know what the class path is from system to system? Is it relative to JAR file?

Comment: @briangonzalez: `[task terminate]` kills the task. If you want your program to wait until the task is finished, then register for the `NSTaskDidTerminateNotification`.

Comment: @briangonzalez: Questions concerning the Java classpath are better asked separately in a Java-related forum, that has nothing to do with Objective C or Cocoa.

Comment: I would argue that this question is at the intersection of Java & Cocoa, that's why the question (and answer) is littered with jargon from both. However, thanks for the answer :)

Comment: I still was not able to get this to work using `-classpath`, although this seems like the most straightforward approach. However, a simple solution I found was to throw all of my logic into a file called `run.sh`, then I was able invoke that script using `NSTask`. In the script I was able to `cd` then `java -jar` to run my jar file. This worked like a charm.

Comment: @briangonzalez: Perhaps your Java program requires "/path/to" to be the current working directory? Try adding `[task setCurrentDirectoryPath:@"/path/to"]` before launching the task.